# What does Leggett mean by quantum states like $|\psi\rangle=(a|\psi_1\rangle+b|\psi_2\rangle)^N$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, definition, notation

In his [article](https://zh.booksc.eu/book/83623531/888c52) (p. 1986) Legett uses the notation  $|\psi\rangle=(a|\psi_1\rangle+b|\psi_2\rangle)^N$ to classify "macroscopic quantum phenomena". Does the "$^N$" mean "$\bigotimes_{l=1}^n$" (tensor product)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does.

Some people use the notation $|\psi\rangle^{\otimes N}$ to make that extra clear.